# PowerShell Get-Content: Try{ .. } catch { ..}?

Tags: file, powershell

I did

```
try {
    $g = Get-Content $file
} catch { 
    return ""
}
```

But the as soon as an another process still writes into $file (and blocks it) I get an error message: Can't access the file as..

Why am I not 'landing' in catch {} but getting the error - how can I check whether the file is accessible?

Thanks in advance,
Golly

Got IT :)

I just use :

```
 try {
     $g = New-Object system.IO.StreamReader $file
 } catch { 
     return ""
 }
```

and in case the file is still written it redirects to the catch-branch

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In a Try/Catch the Catch block is only invoked on terminating errors.  Use -ErrorAction Stop on your cmdlets to force all errors to be terminating:

```
try {
    $g = Get-Content $file -ErrorAction Stop
} catch { 
    return ""
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that's the appreciated solution!

Comment: This answer didn't work for me, perhaps because I'm also using the flag `-Raw`. The only alternative I found was using `Test-Path -Path "<path + filename>"` prior trying to get the content.